# Android simple percentage layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to have a fullscreen row with elements on Android?
I tried to do it with table, GridView and linear, but I'm struggling with it since quite a time now and couldn't find a post that helped me.

I just made a small picture of what I'd like to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eci5E.png[image]

In short point:

- Label and Button should just be as big as their content and fit to the biggest label in the column
- The button should stick on the right side
- The label should stick on the left side
- The textbox should just fill the leftover space between label/button, but in the case of bigger content, it shouldn't "kick out" the button on the right...

My last try was the GridView, which looks a kind of acceptable, but not really.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add nutrition part"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Selected part"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""
                android:enabled="false"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Button
                android:text="Find nutrition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Gram"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartGram"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

            <Button
                android:text="Abort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartButtonAbort"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartButtonAdd"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

The ConstraintLayout did a quite good job for my purpose - thanks for good hint Luca:

[image: Task description]

Code looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add nutrition part"
                android:id="@+id/headline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Selected part"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""
                android:enabled="false"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition" />

            <Button
                android:text="Find nutrition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Gram"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartGram"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition" />

            <Button
                android:text="Abort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartButtonAbort"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartGram" />

            <Button
                android:text="Add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartButtonAdd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartButtonAbort"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartGram" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you achieve the goal using grid layout or any other

Comment: No, didtn work (or i dont know how, i guess), I tried the GridLayout, but this button is scrolled out, and i cant get the textbox to just fill the leftover space

Comment: `... to just fill the leftover space` Then use `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: which text u need leftoverspace  mention the particular id's

Comment: match_parent is the size of the whole screen, the button gets kicked out then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) to achieve this, [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) you can find an explanation of it.

Your layout file should look like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add nutrition part"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selected part"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMakeMealPartFindNutrition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialogMakeMealPartNutrition"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Find nutrition"/>

    ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```